# mysql insert can't with select into outfile?

Tags: mysql, insert

```
mysql> insert into helpme set user=(select 0x616361 into outfile 'c://windows//temp//test.ini');
Database changed

mysql> select * from helpme;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| user                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | id    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |     1 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 37833 |
| aca                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | 37834 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set
```

why user is aca？and can't find the file (c://windows//temp//test.ini)?

Comment: 1) What do you think `0x616361` contains? 2) What happens if you run `select 0x616361 into outfile 'c://windows//temp//test.ini'` separately?

Comment: What do you want to put with 0x616361 as value? Will you have permission to write in 'C:' from database without explicitly granting so?

Comment: 1) 0x616361 unhex --> aca  2)I know select 0x616361 into outfile 'c://windows//temp//test.ini' will write a file in c:/windows/temp/test.ini; but insert into helpme set user=(select 0x616361 into outfile 'c://windows//temp//test.ini') as a statment, mysql should run select 0x616361 into outfile 'c://windows//temp//test.ini (start from right regulation ) first,if success,user=1 and write a file in c:/windows/temp,if failed,user=0 and can't write a file.

Answer (score 2):

[`SELECT … INTO …` can’t be used in a sub-query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html):

> An `INTO` clause should not be used in a nested `SELECT` because such a `SELECT` must return its result to the outer context.

That’s why MySQL chose to return the value instead of writing it into file.